# How do I reset the count using the pandas diff() function when a condition from another column is satisfied?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I am trying to count the number of days between dates (cumulatively), (grouped by a column denoted as id), however, I want to reset the counter whenever a condition is satisfied.

Below I have the following dataframe:

```
     reset_day category       date     id  tdelta
0            N      low 2019-09-04  16876     NaN
1            N      low 2019-09-05  16876     NaN
2            N      low 2019-09-06  16876     NaN
3            N      low 2019-09-07  16876     NaN
4            N      low 2019-09-08  16876     NaN
...        ...      ...        ...    ...     ...
5144         Y   medium 2021-05-23  17612     0.0
5145         Y     high 2021-05-23  23406     0.0
5146         Y     high 2021-05-23  21765     0.0
5147         Y   medium 2021-05-23  19480     0.0
5148         Y   medium 2021-05-23   9066     0.0
```

Here I want to input values into the column “tdelta”, where the values are currently NaN. This column counts the number of days between the “date” column for each id.

However, I am struggling with trying to reset the count based on the column “reset_day”. If the column value is a “Y”, then the count should start again for that particular id. You can already see a value of 0 in such cases in the tdelta column.

I have previously tried  the following on a similar dataframe, by creating another column denoted as test t delta:

```
example = example.sort_values(by="date")
example['date'] = pd.to_datetime(example['date'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
example['test tdelta'] = example.groupby('id')['date'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
example['test tdelta'] = example['test tdelta'].fillna(0)
```

However, this just counts the number of days between the dates for each id and fills in the missing values without the resetting I need.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating an extra grouping column based on the reset day might what you're looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'reset_day':['N','N','Y','N','N','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y'],
                   'category':['low','low','low','low','low','medium','high','high','medium','medium'],
                   'date':['2019-09-04','2019-09-05','2019-09-06','2019-09-07','2019-09-08','2021-05-23','2021-05-23','2021-05-23','2021-05-23','2021-05-23'],
                   'id':[16876,16876,16876,16876,16876,17612,23406,21765,19480,9066]
                   })


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
df = df.sort_values(['id','date'])

#create extra grouping column based on reset day
df['reset_group'] = df['reset_day'].replace({'N':False,'Y':True})
df['reset_group'] = df.groupby('id')['reset_group'].cumsum()

#use extra grouping column when calculating differences
df['tdelta'] = df.groupby(['id','reset_group'])['date'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['tdelta'] = df.groupby(['id','reset_group'])['tdelta'].cumsum().fillna(0)
```

```
print(df)

  reset_day category       date     id  reset_group  tdelta
9         Y   medium 2021-05-23   9066            1     0.0
0         N      low 2019-09-04  16876            0     0.0
1         N      low 2019-09-05  16876            0     1.0
2         Y      low 2019-09-06  16876            1     0.0
3         N      low 2019-09-07  16876            1     1.0
4         N      low 2019-09-08  16876            1     2.0
5         Y   medium 2021-05-23  17612            1     0.0
8         Y   medium 2021-05-23  19480            1     0.0
7         Y     high 2021-05-23  21765            1     0.0
6         Y     high 2021-05-23  23406            1     0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have an additional question if you don't mind: Say I want to count backwards from the reset day, would I create additional columns to achieve this?

Comment: After creating the extra grouping column, could you just re-sort your data with dates in reverse order? Then it should basically be the same logic with finding the differences and cumulative sum, then sorting the final result again if needed.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it was as simple as this `df = df.sort_values(by='date', ascending=False)`